# How to filter in array of objects within a single json document in mongodb?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, nosql

I am quite a newbie to mongodb, my requirement is to filter within the array of objects of a single document

for example :  Below is my json document. I want to query in the combinations to find all the Manufacturer with value "abc manufacturer".

The query I tried is 
`db.Product.find({"Combinations": {$elemMatch: {"Manufacturer":"abc manufacturer"}}})`. unfortunately its not returning the result with abc manufacturer but all.

My result should be exactly similar to the screenshot attached down below. Since its in sql server, Now I want the equivalent query for the same in mongodb.. Some experts in the forum throw me some light.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CukNP.png)

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e8c938ab3166800493273f"),
    "ProductId" : 26,
    "Combinations" : [ 
        {
            "#Type" : "S",
            "Manufacturer" : "abc manufacturer",
            "Model Name" : "Squatting Urinal",
            "Size" : "475 x 365 x 105 mm",
            "Colour" : "White"
        }, 
        {
            "#Type" : "S",
            "Manufacturer" : "abc manufacturer",
            "Model Name" : "Squatting",
            "Size" : "430 x 350 x 100 mm"
        }, 
        {
            "#Type" : "S",
            "Manufacturer" : "def manufacturer",
            "Model Name" : "Squatting Urinal",
            "Size" : "440 x 355 x 102 mm",
            "Colour" : "White"
        }, 
        {
            "#Type" : "S",
            "Manufacturer" : "xyz manufacturer",
            "Model Name" : "Squatting Urinal",
            "Size" : "440 x 355 x 102 mm",
            "Colour" : "Ivory"
        }, 
        {
            "#Type" : "S",
            "Manufacturer" : "ghi manufacturer",
            "Model Name" : "Squatting Pan - 861"
        }, 
        {
            "#Type" : "S",
            "Manufacturer" : "xyz manufacturer",
            "Model Name" : "Mateo",
            "Size" : "470 x 365 x 100 mm"
        }, 
        {
            "#Type" : "S",
            "Manufacturer" : "xyz manufacturer",
            "Model Name" : "Squatting",
            "Size" : "340 x 435 x 100 mm",
            "Colour" : "White"
        }
    ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are searching for, is all the **Combinations** where the **Manufacturer** is *abc*.
The query you just did gives you all the Documents that contains a **Combination** with the said **Manufacturer**.

You should check the `aggregations` for that.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/